# In a DB2 SQL function, is there an equivalent to the Finally block in JAVA and .Net..?

Tags: db2, db2-400

In DB2-400 v7.3, do functions or procedures have an equivalent to the `Finally` block as found in JAVA..? To quote the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> The `Finally` block always executes when the try block exits.

It's used for cleanup purposes needed by that section of code. In a DB2 function, it could be used for dropping temporary objects, such as Declared global temporary tables.

If DB2 doesn't have such a feature, it's not the end of the world. It can easily be simulated in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global Temporary Tables go away when the job ends, so no need to clean them up. SQL does not have a try() catch() block, so no there is no finally clause either.

You can write stored procedures in Java if you need that functionality, but I would expect those to be less performant as SQL stored procedures are compiled using C (which also doesn't have a finally block).

Alternatively you could write your stored procedures with RPGLE sub-procedures which do have an on-exit block which runs when the sub-procedure ends whether that is a normal or an abnormal end.

Comment: True. I got to a point where I was going to write some self-housekeeping into this function. Unless I'm mistaken, this version of DB2 (for i 7.3) doesn't have JAVA. As for RPG...there are only so many hours in the day.

Comment: According to the 7.3 [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzcrtpef.htm) The supported languages for stored procedures are: `C`, `C++`, `CL`, `COBOL`, `COBOLLE`, `JAVA`, `PLI`, `REXX`, `RPG`, and `RPGLE`.

Comment: I was under the impression our system doesn't have Java, or it's somehow disabled. C++ is similar enough to Java that I can usually read & understand it, but the rest I know next to nothing about. That being said, your comment brings up an interesting point for a new question for the DB2 tag: "how do I determine what languages are accessible on our DB2 system..?"

Comment: You can use `GO LICPGM`, then option 10 to display installed licensed programs. Search for "Java SE" in the description. If you can find it, you have Java.

Comment: Well, there's the answer. When I type `GO LICPGM`, nothing happens, blank [or hidden] screen. Probably due to this new hosted/shared system we moved to. Less maintenance, but also less freedom. Many commands are disabled, and no access to the file system. However, I did try the command on our old private server which is still up & running, and it worked fine. I could see `C++`, `COBOL`, `RPG`, etc. I suppose I could simply try to create a stored procedure/function in `JAVA` and see what happens. If it works, woohoo. If not, ah well. I've been wanting to do a UPC check-digit validator anyways.

Comment: You could try and see if the `JAVA` command is there. Just type `JAVA` and press `F4`.

Comment: It says: `Command JAVA in library QJAVA not allowed.` so it sounds like they have it disabled.

Comment: Maybe you can have your administrator get it activated, or you are stuck with compiled languages. Fortunately free-form `RPG` is very easy to learn, or you have the option of `C/C++`.

Comment: It's probably unlikely we could get it enabled. This system is the order/inventory/bookeeping system our company runs on. Previously we had a private server that the vendor maintained for us, but recently we moved to their cloud-based system. It's mostly the same SQL database, but the ASP we're on is shared with many other customers. So anything that could potentially affect others is locked down. For instance, no access to the file system, and no more iNavigator. It's probably also why Java is disabled; it could use file functions they would have little control over.

Comment: Also, I've been told a number of times on support calls that of any people at any of their other customers, the stuff I do is some of the most complicated, so I'm probably lucky I have what I do, lol.